# How to run asyncpg (Postgresql) multiple queries simultaneously?

Tags: python, postgresql, asynchronous, pool, asyncpg

I'm using PostgreSQL & asyncpg.

```
class PgDb:
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    def __init__(self, conn: asyncpg.connection.Connection):
        self.conn = conn
    async def select(self, sql: str, args: Union[list, Dict[str, Any]] = []) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
        sql, _args = self.__convert_placeholders(sql, args)
        return [dict(row) for row in await self.conn.fetch(sql, *_args)]

class DbPoolSingleton:
    db_pool: Optional[asyncpg.pool.Pool] = None

    @staticmethod
    async def create_pool():
        config = get_postgres_config()
        pool: asyncpg.Pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            ...,
            min_size=30,
            max_size=40
        )
        print("Pool created")
        return pool

    @staticmethod
    async def get_pool() -> asyncpg.pool.Pool:
        if not DbPoolSingleton.db_pool:
            DbPoolSingleton.db_pool = await DbPoolSingleton.create_pool()
        return DbPoolSingleton.db_pool

    @staticmethod
    async def terminate_pool():
        (await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()).terminate()
        DbPoolSingleton.db_pool = None
        print("Pool terminated")
```

```
import asyncio
from helpers.pg_rdb_helper import DbPoolSingleton, PgDb
async def test_synchronous():
    conn = await (await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()).acquire()
    db = PgDb(conn)
    sql = """samplesql"""
    total_start = start = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    for i in range(20):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        rows = await db.select(sql)
        end  = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(f"{i}st query took: ", (end-start).total_seconds())
    total_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"total query took: ", (total_end-total_start).total_seconds())
```

=> **total query took:  2.131297**

```
async def test_asynchronous():
    db_pool = await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()
    sql = """samplesql"""
    total_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    tasks = []
    for i in range(20):
        db = PgDb(await db_pool.acquire())
        task = asyncio.create_task(db.select(sql))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    total_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"total query took: ", (total_end-total_start).total_seconds())
```

===> **total query took:  2.721282**

---

Here, I have a function which is simple multiple queries call, the first version is synchronous version which await every single query without using `asyncio`, the second one is using `asyncio.gather` to run these query in background (at least this is my assumption).

Then turn out, as you saw the result `asynchronous version` was completely slower than `synchronous version`. Basically I know in `asynchronous version` we have some overhead for getting connection from pool for every single query which caused it a bit slower.

So how could we fix `asynchronous version` to take advandtage of `asyncpg` and `asyncio`.

---

After I investigate, I have some fix for this `asynchronous version` but bot of them got some error.

***Asynchronous fix 1***

```
async def test_asynchronous():
    db_pool = await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()
    sql = """samplesql"""
    total_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    tasks = []
    async with db_pool.acquire() as conn:
        db = PgDb(conn)
        for i in range(20):
            task = asyncio.create_task(db.select(sql))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    total_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"total query took: ", (total_end-total_start).total_seconds())
```

I got this error ===>

```
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

### Basically, this fix make multiple coroutine using the same connection to db, so that I got this error..

Now, I gave up with this problem, please help me to resolve it??

My question: **So how could we fix `asynchronous version` to take advandtage of `asyncpg` and `asyncio`.**

Comment: All of your tasks use the same connection from the pool.  Also, your example is not reproducible since you do not show the definition of `PgDB`.

Comment: @jjanes
Sorry it's my fault when I edit the post, I fixed.

Comment: @MikeOrganek
There're not thing special in PgDb class, it just wrapper for execute query of asyncpg.

Comment: @MikeOrganek
a you talking about asynchronous version one?
Yes, so how could I use multiple connection for concurrent tasks without some overhead when we open connection from pool

Comment: It looks to me like the working version already does take advantage of asyncpg.  It is just that there is no advantage to be had. If your undisclosed query already uses all the resources the server has available, harassing the server with multiple at the same time won't it accomplish much.

Comment: You are getting only one connection from the pool.  You then create twenty tasks that all use that same connection.  Have each task acquire a separate connection from the pool, instead.

Comment: @jjanes
Hmmmm,  I agreed with you, but I just wonder how could we use asyncio and asyncpg to take advantage of asynchronous programming?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  If there no advantage to be had, how can you take advantage of it?  Make your SQL be something which would obviously benefit from concurrent execution, like 'select pg_sleep(5)', and try it with your first two formulations (the ones that don't throw errors) and see if the 2nd of them gives a benefit compared to the first.  If it does, then you know the technique works even if it doesn't benefit your real-world case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use the same connection from the pool in all of the tasks you create in your async function.

Try this working example where the tasks each acquire its own connection from the pool:

```
from typing import Optional
import asyncio, datetime
import asyncpg

TRIALS = 200
SQL = "select count(*) from users"

class DbPoolSingleton:
    db_pool: Optional[asyncpg.pool.Pool] = None

    @staticmethod
    async def create_pool():
        pool: asyncpg.Pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            min_size=1,
            max_size=10
        )
        print("Pool created")
        return pool

    @staticmethod
    async def get_pool() -> asyncpg.pool.Pool:
        if not DbPoolSingleton.db_pool:
            DbPoolSingleton.db_pool = await DbPoolSingleton.create_pool()
        return DbPoolSingleton.db_pool

    @staticmethod
    async def terminate_pool():
        (await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()).terminate()
        DbPoolSingleton.db_pool = None
        print("Pool terminated")


async def test_synchronous() -> None:
    conn = await(await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()).acquire()
    total_start = start = datetime.datetime.now()
    runtime_total = 0.0
    for i in range(TRIALS):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        result = await conn.fetchval(SQL)
        end  = datetime.datetime.now()
        qruntime = (end - start).total_seconds()
        runtime_total += qruntime
        #print(f"{i}st query took:  {qruntime} to get {result}")
    total_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"sync  total query took:  {(total_end-total_start).total_seconds()} wallclock seconds and {runtime_total} run seconds")

async def run_query(pool, sql) -> tuple:
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        qstart = datetime.datetime.now()
        result = await conn.fetchval(sql)
        qend = datetime.datetime.now()
        return (result, (qend - qstart).total_seconds())


async def test_asynchronous() -> None:
    pool = await DbPoolSingleton.get_pool()
    total_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    #runtime_total = 0.0
    tasks = []
    for i in range(TRIALS):
        tasks.append(run_query(pool, SQL))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    runtime_total = sum([t[1] for t in results])
    total_end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"async total query took:  {(total_end-total_start).total_seconds()} wallclock seconds and {runtime_total} run seconds")
    # print(f"total query took:  {(total_end-total_start).total_seconds()} wallclock seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test_synchronous())
    loop.run_until_complete(test_asynchronous())    
    loop.run_until_complete(test_synchronous())
    loop.run_until_complete(test_asynchronous())
```

Comment: I didn't see any difference between your asynchronous version and mine?
They're exactly the same idea then asynchronous version was still much

Comment: @DFXNguyễn  Look again.  They are not the same. You said that your code fails with "another operation is in progress".  My code does not fail.  Why would you make such a false assertion as "They are exactly the same idea. . ." ?

Comment: Ognanek.
"another operation is in progress" was caught in the `Asynchronous fix 1`, that's not my proper version, I just list it out for you guys.
Meanwhile your version is the same as the original asynchronous version that I made in the beginning of this post which took 2.721282s to finish.
Btw, did you make the test and see the difference I meant the result?

Comment: @DFXNguyễn  First, do not acquire a connection from the pool from outside of the task you need to run concurrently.  Second, rewrite your code to call `acquire()` from inside of the task, and surround it with an `async with` context (which is why I asked you to show the code for PgDb).  Third, show some respect and do not forget that you are the one asking for help here.  The code I posted runs the async version in less than one third the time of the sync version on my machine.  If you want to insist that my code is the same as your original code, then programming may not be for you.

Comment: Oraganek, 
I'm so sorry, I didn't to meant to show any disrespect here.
Thank you so much for your help, that's completely my mistake, 
I finally understood it.

Comment: @DFXNguyễn I apologize for getting testy.  It seemed to me that you were quick to dismiss my suggestions as irrelevant or functionally identical to your attempts.  I provided a self-contained script that you should have been able to copy/paste and run after fixing the `SQL` and `TRIALS` constants.  Concurrency is difficult to do correctly in any language, and Python makes it seem deceptively simple when details like where the connections are acquired and using a context manager to ensure returning a connection to the pool matter very much.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

As you said, the error is because there are multiple operations being performed simultaneously. You can fix with this error by adding "await db.select(sql)" in your code.

What it does is that it waits for previous query to finish before starting with the new one. The problem with this is that the **overall execution time will increase**.

**Code:**

```
 async with db_pool.acquire() as conn:
     for i in range(20):
         db = PgDb(conn)
         await db.select(sql)
```

Comment: Well, your fix is completely the same as my `synchronous version`.
So there're not any improvement here.
I'm finding the way to take advantage of asyncio and asyncpg.